# Not able to access NSMutableArray from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've read through many posts here but I can't seem to make my array available in another class.

I want to access the array plusTransactions in CPPHistoryViewController (a table controller, in a container as a child of CPPSecondViewController) from class CPPSecondViewController.

CPPSecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CPPSecondViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *plustransactions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *campustransactions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *mealtransactions;

@end
```

CPPSecondViewController.m

```
#import "CPPSecondViewController.h"
@interface CPPSecondViewController ()
@implementation CPPSecondViewController
@end

@synthesize plustransactions = _plustransactions;
@synthesize campustransactions = _campustransactions;
@synthesize mealtransactions = _mealtransactions;

...

_plustransactions = newPlustransactions;
NSLog(@"%@", newPlustransactions);
NSLog(@"%@%lu", @"That's how many: ", (unsigned long)_plustransactions.count);
CPPHistoryViewController *historyView = [[CPPHistoryViewController alloc]init];
[historyView.tableView reloadData];
```

This is good, returns all of my array items and count is 7.

CPPHistoryViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CPPHistoryViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end
```

CPPHistoryViewController.m

```
#import "CPPHistoryViewController.h"
#import "CPPSecondViewController.h"
#import "CPPPlusTransaction.h"
#import "CPPCampusTransaction.h"
#import "CPPMealTransaction.h"
#import "CPPHistoryCell.h"

@interface CPPHistoryViewController ()

@end

@implementation CPPHistoryViewController

...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    CPPSecondViewController *secondView = [[CPPSecondViewController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *plusTransactions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    plusTransactions = secondView.plustransactions;
    NSMutableArray *campusTransactions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    campusTransactions = secondView.campustransactions;
    NSMutableArray *mealTransactions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    mealTransactions = secondView.mealtransactions;
    NSLog(@"Table formatting called");
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)secondView.segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex);
    switch (secondView.segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"%@%lu", @"PlusTransactions", (unsigned long)plusTransactions.count);
            return plusTransactions.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"%@%lu", @"CampusTransactions", (unsigned long)campusTransactions.count);
            return campusTransactions.count;
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"%@%lu", @"MealTransactions", (unsigned long)mealTransactions.count);
            return mealTransactions.count;
            break;
    }
    return 1;
}

...

@end
```

Here's where things get weird. Any array I call from here returns with a count of 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Make your properties `strong` and try..

Comment: I just tried that, but the count still returns 0. Could it have to do with the tableview being reloaded (so the numberofRowsInSection function is called twice)?

Comment: It appears that you're allocating secondView and then throwing it away.  I'm guessing that you're creating another copy somewhere else and that's where you're initializing the arrays, but that's an entirely different object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you want is to get the array data stored in `CPPSecondViewController` to be availalbe in `CPPHistoryViewController`. But as per the code you posted,

```
CPPHistoryViewController *historyView = [[CPPHistoryViewController alloc]init];
[historyView.tableView reloadData];
```

This just create new instance and the tableView inside the view is reloaded. But in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you are creating new instance of `CPPSecondViewController`, thats wrong.

What you can do is, simply pass the `CPPSecondViewController` instance before reloading tableView.

In CPPHistoryViewController.h, create a property for keeping secondView like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CPPSecondViewController *secondView;
```

then, change your code in CPPSecondViewController like below:

```
CPPHistoryViewController *historyView = [[CPPHistoryViewController alloc]init];
historyView.secondView = self;
[historyView.tableView reloadData];
```

Also, remove alloc init statements from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, just use `secondView.plustransactions` here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok. Should that line where the alloc init was be like this? CPPSecondViewController *secondView = secondView.plustransactions; Xcode is saying that secondView will be initialized...

Comment: You already have secondView as class property, just use that in cellForRowAtIndexPath. eg:NSLog(@"%@%lu", @"PlusTransactions", (unsigned long)secondView.plusTransactions.count);

Answer (score 1):

```
 CPPSecondViewController *secondView = [[CPPSecondViewController alloc] init];
```

Here you are creating a new object, So all values are nill.
Here you can only set values in to second view controller.

in your History class, you nedd to create a property of a second class they you can set value in to Second class

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Secondclass* secondclass;

[secondClass setAry: ary];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CPPSecondViewController *secondView = [[CPPSecondViewController alloc] init];
```

in this code, the view controller is just init, the properties is all nil, it's a new view controller instance.

setup properties in init method, or access the second view's view property, to load view, to trigger the property initialize.

if you want reference the second view controller from history view controller, you can add a property in history view controller refer to second view controller.

in CPPHistoryViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) CPPSecondViewController *secondViewController;
```

and set this property in your show code.

in CPPSecondViewController.m

```
_plustransactions = newPlustransactions;
NSLog(@"%@", newPlustransactions);
NSLog(@"%@%lu", @"That's how many: ", (unsigned long)_plustransactions.count);
CPPHistoryViewController *historyView = [[CPPHistoryViewController alloc]init];
historyView.secondViewController = self;
[historyView.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly do I trigger the properties to initialize? I'm kind of new to Objective-C.

Comment: @cdamayor use the other solution. I think you want refer to the second view from history view, so just past the second view to history view.